# Xamarin MVVM pass object properties

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, parameters

So I'm pretty new to the whole MVVM thing. I pretty much understand the basics of it. I have an example that's working just find as it is but I'm trying to change it into the MVVM style. Im just trying out different examples so I can learn.

(LoginPage.xaml)

On the XAML side I have a label with a tap gesture. pretty single

```
<!--  Existing Tab  -->
            <Label x:Name="labelName"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Style="{StaticResource CenteredTextTitle}"
                   Text="Log In">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="SelectorOption_Tapped" />
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
```

LoginPage.xaml.cs page

I can access it by creating a tapped function.

```
private async void SelectorOption_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(sender is Xamarin.Forms.View view)) return;

            int index = Grid.GetColumn(view);

           ...
        }
```

now im trying to change that into MVVM..
So the XAML stays the same

on the ViewModel page
loginpageviewmodel.cs page

```
public LoginPageViewModel()
    {
        btnSubmit_Clicked = new Command(SubmitClicked);
    }

    public ICommand btnSubmit_Clicked { get; set; }

    private void SubmitClicked(object parameter)
    {
        if (!(parameter is Xamarin.Forms.View view)) return;

        var index = Grid.GetColumn(view);
     }
```

i can run the function submitclicked. But i cant pass on the parameter. Its always null.
i want to get the column from the grid that i have based on what the user selects. it works fine the original way but if i try to change it to MVVM i cant pass the view form to get the getcolumn..
is there anyway i can pass that.?

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Yes.. that worked thank for the help.. Just accept it.. thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter comes from the `CommandParameter` you set in the xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label x:Name="myLabel" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Text="Log In">
        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding btnSubmit_Clicked}" CommandParameter="{x:Reference myLabel}"/>
        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
    </Label>
</StackLayout>
```

In code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new LoginPageViewModel();
    }
}

public class LoginPageViewModel
{

    public LoginPageViewModel()
    {
        btnSubmit_Clicked = new Command(SubmitClicked);
    }

    public ICommand btnSubmit_Clicked { get; set; }

    private void SubmitClicked(object parameter)
    {
        if (!(parameter is Xamarin.Forms.View view)) return;

        Console.WriteLine(parameter);
    }
}
```